# C - Array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

im having a txt file

> abc=123  def=456  ...

I have defined my struct like this:

```
 typedef struct rule {
    char* old;
    char* new;
 }Rule;
```

I have counted the ammount of these rules via function

> int count_rules();

Now I'm calling this function in another, while making dictionary of rules

```
void make_dic(){
 ammount_rules = count_rules();
 //here goes the problem
 Rule *dictionary = malloc(ammount_rules * sizeof(Rule));
}
```

I want to scan another txt and replace old with new so I'd like to acces every twin with simple command

```
for (i=0; i<ammount_rules;i++){
  if ( (string_in_text) == (dictionary.old[i]) )
  {
  printf("%s" dictionary.new[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: To compare two strings you use [the `strcmp` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), not `==`.

Comment: What problems are you having?  What question are you asking?

Comment: i know thanks :) I just simlified to show my intension of mallocing array

Comment: Ablenky: I'm having problem with creating some sort of array which i can browse with for cycle and compare strings

Comment: "I want to scan another txt ",  I suspect `char* old;
    char* new;` lacking allocated memory to hold the strings is will cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your `malloc` seems to be fine. It allocates an array of `Rule` with `ammount_rules` elements.

However, the way you use `dictionary` seems wrong.

```
dictionary.old[i]  // wrong

dictionary[i].old  // correct

dictionary.new[i]  // wrong

dictionary[i].new  // correct
```

BTW: Notice that you are comparing pointers - not strings. Use `strcmp` for comparing strings.

Comment: Thank you! Now i tried for cycle under my malloc command and wrote:(for length of rules){dictionary[i].old = 'try'; printf("%s", dictioanry[i].old);} program stopped working, can you help me? i'm desperate now, i'ts been hours EDIT: haha i got it, i should have used "" instead of ' ' i'm piece of #... haha thanks mate! you saved me!

Comment: Again me, what if i want to add char instead of string into my dictionary[i].old? this makes my program stop working:(for length of rules){dictionary[i].old[i] = 'c'; printf("%c", dictioanry[i].old[i]);}

Comment: @MirEso I think you should ask a new question so that you can post your code as it is now. I'm sure you get help.